# What does a cursor for `Select * from table where ='something '`return if no data is selected

Tags: mysql-python

I wanted to know what a Select query return if No rows is selected, will it be NULL or something else:

eq

```
cursor.execute(Select * from table where data= "YES")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the query returns data the following applies:

```
import MySQLdb
conn = MySQLdb.Connection(...)
curs = conn.cursor()
print curs.execute("select * from cities where city like 'San %'")
51 //51 rows found
rows = curs.fetchall()
print len(rows)
51 // as stated above 51 rows found
```

Yet if your query return 0 rows you'll get an empty list

```
if not rows:
   # empty set returned
```

Comment: which means that @Baklap4
`if no rows:
      do something
else:
      do something`

Comment: If that's what you want yes. I hope this helped you out :)

Comment: Yes thanks i was trying `if rows==NULL` but it dint works , i will try with what us sugested thanks.